# MySQL 1064 Error Creating a Linking Table (Many-to-Many)

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064, create-table

I'm trying to understand why a parsing error occurred (1064) with the following code.

> <#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '' at line 3>

```
CREATE TABLE Party_Library
(
    Party INT(11)
    Library varchar(40)
    PRIMARY KEY (Library,Party)
    FOREIGN KEY (Party) REFERENCES Party(PartyKey) ON DELETE CASCADE
    FOREIGN KEY (Library) REFERENCES MusicLibraries(MusicSource) ON DELETE CASCADE
)
```

Comment: You forgot the comma?

Comment: Yep, that solved it. John Conde gave a specific answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing commas after each declaration:

```
CREATE TABLE Party_Library
(
    Party INT(11),
    Library varchar(40),
    PRIMARY KEY (Library,Party),
    FOREIGN KEY (Party) REFERENCES Party(PartyKey) ON DELETE CASCADE,
    FOREIGN KEY (Library) REFERENCES MusicLibraries(MusicSource) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```